# Update specific field(s) in each row in a database using python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite

Say I have the following table:

```
id  | name | age
----+------+----
1     john   30
2     doe    22
```

and I want to update the `age` and `name` of the row with `id=2` to 32 and `tom`, using python e.g `sqlalchemy`

I'm using a PostgreSQL database (and sqlite for dev).

Comment: Read the docs [Update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) and you will find you are wrong. Though an `UPDATE` of any kind in Postgres is actually an `DELETE/INSERT` so you will have an old and new row for some period of time.

Comment: *I know there's the update SQL arguement but that updates the entire row*. No, it updates only the columns that you choose to update: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update/

Comment: My bad - that has been removed and updated

Comment: Go here [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/) and in `Search terms:` box at top of page enter `update`. There is a host of methods that apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` you want is:

```
update t
   set name = 'tom',
       age = 32
   where id = 2;
```

In the `update` syntax, you list the columns that are changing.  I am not aware of a syntax that replaces all columns in a row, without specifying the column names.

Under the hood, the database (generally) is replacing the entire row.  But that is invisible to you.  In fact, what gets written is generally a *data page* with many rows on them.  I wouldn't worry about the internal mechanisms if you are learning the basics of SQL.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to write that I'm using Python e.g `sqlalchemy` - I doubt it doesn't change the syntax?

Comment: @CutePoison . . . It should support basically the same syntax.  This is the SQL syntax and is common to all databases.